# How to use depencey injection pattern with custom external .NET Standard DLLs

Tags: razor, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET Core so excuse me in advance if my question is vague. I have been reading about the Dependency Injection pattern and I think its great but I have not been able to find an example of how to make use of this pattern with external dlls built with .Net Standard. I am starting a new project in asp.net core razor pages and I would like to follow the DI pattern but I need to make use of a few in-house-built dlls and I am not sure how. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It really depends on specifically how the classes in those external DLL's are implemented. For example, do the classes have interfaces that expose their functionality? If not, you might need to change them, or write wrappers around them.

Comment: @mason thanks for your comment. No those classes do not have interfaces. Does this mean that the only way to make use of those classes is to just create a new instance whenever needed using the "new" keyword?

Comment: Ideally, all classes (other than those that contain just properties, no logic) should have a corresponding interface. Then those would be injected via constructor injection into classes that need them. The classes that need them will depend on those classes via interface, not via a direct dependency. A good rule of thumb is that you shouldn't use the "new" keyword unless you're creating a class that contains no logic (view models are a good example).

Comment: I suggest you watch [Deep Dive into Dependency Injection and Writing Decoupled Quality Code and Testable Software](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412) which will give you a much better idea of how to structure your code. The video is long, but the whole thing is worth watching. It really transformed my code and helped advance my career (and salary!)

Comment: @mason thank you very much. Will definitely watch the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add references to your project.
2. Register your types/instances in the `Startup` class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<LibraryDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("LibraryContext"));

    services.AddTransient<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();

    services.AddTransient<IAuthorRepository, AuthorRepository>();

    services.AddTransient<IBookRepository, BookRepository>();

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

3. Comsume in your controller

```
public class AuthorController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAuthorRepository _authorRepository;

    public AuthorController(IAuthorRepository authorRepository)
    {
        _authorRepository = authorRepository;
    }
}
```

4. Or resolve somewhere else

```
public static class DbInitializer
{
    public static void Seed(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
        {
            var repository = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IAuthorRepository>();
        }
    }
}
```

All examples are from my GitHub repository, can be found [here](https://github.com/MiroslavMikus/Course.LibraryManagement). Feel free to star/clone/fork :)